# Python scraping (Image)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I managed to get everything I wanted except the image I would like to download this image into the current directory this is the html of image

```
<div class="pull-left custom-photo">
  <a href="javascript:newWindow('https://www.example.com/cover/6EB90E2A3A54EB14810A178E4A5FF927/');"><img src="https://static.example.com/media/6EB90E2A3A54EB14810A178E4A5FF927/t_cover_6EB90E2A3A54EB14810A178E4A5FF927.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/></a>
</div>
```

I need to get image that is in

```
<a href="javascript:newWindow('HERE');"><img src="https://static.metart.com/media/6EB90E2A3A54EB14810A178E4A5FF927/t_cover_6EB90E2A3A54EB14810A178E4A5FF927.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/></a>
```

I tried with:

```
imgSec = soup.find('div',{'class':'pull-left custom-photo'})
for item in imgSec.find_all('a'):
    url = item.get('href')
```

but I cannot extract first link after `javascript:newWindow`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please read up on the site rules before posting. You have to include code in your post.

Comment: `"javascript:newWindow ..."` is normal string so use standard string functions like `split()` or slicing `text[start:stop]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal string so use standard string functions - ie. slicing `text[22:-3]`

```
text = "javascript:newWindow('https://www.example.com/cover/6EB90E2A3A54EB14810A178E4A5FF927/');" 
print text[22:-3]

https://www.example.com/cover/6EB90E2A3A54EB14810A178E4A5FF927/
```

Comment: Sliced it nicely but now python still can't obtain image because I'm trying to take image from https://www.example.com/cover/FD2882C4965A1DC4B95863ECD28A40F0 instead of https://static.example.com/media/FD2882C4965A1DC4B95863ECD28A40F0/cover_FD2882C4965A1DC4B95863ECD28A40F0.jpg

Comment: Is there a way to get this image I didn't saw this code for static image in page info

Comment: use `urllib` or `requests.get()` to get data from this link and later save it in file.